# Jquery-ui-1.7.2 Want to Highlight dates between pickup and return date

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, calendar

i am using Jquery-ui 1.7.2 calendar in my project. I have Jquery-ui-1.7.2.js and Jquery-ui-1.7.2.css for my calender.

When i select pickup and return date, both are shown in red color. But, I also want to highlight dates between these two in my calendar with my choice of color.

Please help me out with code.

Answer (score 1):

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kVsbq/4/)**

Try this:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        numberOfMonths: [12,1],
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input1").val());
            var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input2").val());
            return [true, date1 && ((date.getTime() == date1.getTime()) || (date2 && date >= date1 && date <= date2)) ? "dp-highlight" : ""];
        },
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input1").val());
            var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input2").val());
            if (!date1 || date2) {
                $("#input1").val(dateText);
                $("#input2").val("");
                $(this).datepicker();
            } else {
                $("#input2").val(dateText);
                $(this).datepicker();
            }
        }
    });
```